# Simple loop works in Java but not "Android"

Tags: android, loops

I am having an issue getting a simple loop that runs in Java just fine to work in Android.

I created a textview and set that up just for a test run. When I run this I get one number to appear in the box and that's it, it never changes to another number.

I tried this with for loops but all I ever get was the title bar then a black screen then a crash.

No errors in Eclipse and she does run and without errors just no number updates.

If your wondering about the second while loop it is kinda like a pause so you can see the numbers appear slower and works in plain Java.

Just and FYI I have been learning Java for exactly 2 weeks from watching vids on youtube. I have created a few Android apps that do tiddly stuff but just cannot get a loop to well loop in Android.

Thanks for any help for the new guy.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView display;
    int counter;
    int min = 1;
    int max = 5;
    int counter2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        while(counter < 10){
        Random r = new Random();
        int rn = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        String rando = Integer.toString(rn);
        display.setText(rando);


        while(counter2  < 5000){
            counter2++;
            }
        counter++;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never instantiated counter or counter2. You have to set them to 0 first...

Comment: Sorry about that, I knew to set those and did at one point but a video showed them not set to 0. I set them to 0 by adding = 0; to the int. Still no go.

Comment: Ah I read your post better. Why do you expect it to display thousands of numbers? Sure it's inefficient and will take a while, but it's displaying numbers at the same rate it computes them, which is incredibly fast. If you want to watch it go up over time, add a Thread.sleep(100) call in there

Comment: your counter2 is only going to pause once. and that 5000 is not seconds. that 5000 does not represent seconds FYI.   Your better off creating a separate thread since android has a 3 or 5 second non responsive timeout. So if you hold up onCreate for too long it will freeze your app.  also if you did want to use the 5000 then reset the counter2 after setting the random number so that it the second while look can run again.

Comment: It should only change the number 10 times due to counter. then counter2 should act like sleep but allow me to insert code to check for a button press. I increased the variable for counter2 but it didn't help, just seems to show one number and that's it.

Comment: yes it will only show one number because its going to fast for you to see it.

Comment: So I have increased the counter2 and it seems to make the whole app load way slower. So I am figuring that this kinda thing need to go in a thread. So I am looking how to do that and start the thread. This may work because my intention is to display two random numbers and give time for the user to press a button if they match. I have this working fine in regular Java but Android is kicking my butt with where things need to go.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses an event-driven UI model, consisting of `lifecycle event` methods such as onCreate(), onPause(), various key/button methods and so on.  **These are required to accomplish their work and return within a few milliseconds**.

To do longer running tasks - included repeated updates - you will either have to use a Thread other than the main / UI thread, one of the numerous mechanisms which wraps that, or add additional events, such as via a Timer.

Note also that you cannot touch the UI from any thread other than the UI thread, so when your background method decides that it wants to change something in the UI, it must push that actual update operation over to the UI thread, using a mechanism such as runOnUiThread() or a handler.

Comment: I seen the lifecycle event stuff and am reading up a bit more on that now. I was just hoping that Java would move over a bit easier. So it is better to just create a whole other class to run the meat of the program and link back to the UI. Going to have to look into what I need to do to put the loop in it's own class and still settext to textview.

Answer (score 0):

Here just do a toast instead of setting the text view so you can see whats happening and i changed your counter to reset after every update so the next # has a pause .. if your doing it for textview try doing it outside of onCreate() because you can only see the view after its created so thats why your not seeing the change per pause.

```
while(counter < 10){
        Random r = new Random();
        int rn = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        String rando = Integer.toString(rn);
       Toast.makeText(this, rando, 1).show();
       //reset your counter to slow the next # down
       counter2=0;



        while(counter2  < 50){
            counter2++;
            }
       counter++;
        }
```

if you needed to print them out on the textview visually you need to run them on a runnable that gets queued.  Or you could probably make a seperate thread but heres one way without a seperate thread:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView display;
    int counter;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            handler = new Handler();
//this starts the runnable right away
          handler.postDelayed(updateTextRunnable, 0);
        }
    }

    private Runnable updateTextRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          doStuff();

        }
    };

    public void doStuff(){

            Random r = new Random();
            int rn = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            String rando = Integer.toString(rn);
           display.setText(rando);


           //heres the pause, it runs every two seconds 
        if(counter<10)
           handler.postDelayed(updateTextRunnable, 2000);
        counter++;
    }

    }
```

Comment: i really just wanted him to see whats happening, he could have used the logcat as well.

Comment: I took this and left the textview in there. odd that the toaster shows them but not the textview. I'm working on getting this into a runnable or a loop. A whole new chapter in my learning android. I am hoping that this will help a little.

Comment: Let me give that second one a try. I tried creating another class all together and managed to call back bit with the same results. I want to thank you all for helping out a new guy.

Comment: I am reading up on the handler right now. I am seeing how it works. Also reading up on the runnable. This is really helping out as the tutorials all seem to be about splash screens and making buttons do stuff but not much about loops and timers. j2emanue - I will up this once I have enough rep points. This is really helping me heal in the right direction! Thanks again everyone!